# Scroll grid to reveal columns

Tags: javascript, scroll, grid, jasmine, protractor

I need to check in my test if grid contains all necessary columns, but protractor cannot find columns that aren't visible so I need to check a few columns, then scroll and check the rest of columns. Is there any way I can scroll grid? Is this even a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns are not visible at the moment, but are present in the DOM, you can [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the last column to scroll the grid. Something along these lines:

```
var columns = element.all(by.repeater("column in columns"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", columns.last());
```

Comment: Works pretty good. I tried to use something similar, but with no luck. This simple script works great. Thank you :)